# Flutter Throws NEEDS-PAINT on Everything?

Tags: dart, flutter

everyone.

I'm currently in a time crunch to try and build an app in Flutter, and I've run into a slight problem. My app, after I implemented some code written by a colleague, is throwing a NEEDS-PAINT exception when I reach the TeamState state.

[Here's a link to a Git repo that contains all our code in Main.dart.](https://github.com/frc4976/frc2019-scouting-app)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Full error...

```
I/flutter (14688): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#e1773 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
```

Comment: Please post the exact and full error message.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here: I/flutter (14688): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#e1773 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT...

Answer (score 0):

Could be https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27356

which happens when the text passed to `Text(...)` is empty.

Changing such code to

```
text?.isEmpty ?? false ? Container() : Text(text)
```

should fix it.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly is the code you are referring to? (Line #)

Comment: I didn't look at your code, only looked up the error message